# Itext 7 Setting Font Color

Tags: java, fonts, itext7

I am migrating from itext 5 to 7.0.5 and am having trouble with colors. When I try the following:

```
Text title1 = new Text("The Strange Case of ").setFontColor(Color.BLUE);
```

My IDE tells me that Color.BLUE is deprecated. I cannot find what to use instead. Please help. TIA.

Comment: It just warning, you can go ahead and execute code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `com.itextpdf.kernel.color.ColorConstants` as the replacement for `com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color` which was marked depreciated in 7.0.5.

As noted in a comment the `Color` class is simply depreciated in 7.0.5 and both classes act the same way, however in 7.1 the `Color` class will be removed.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.